# Can scheduling price changes of an iOS app make the product unavailable for sale while the price is changed?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itmstransporter

I'm using iTunes Store Transporter to schedule price tier changes for my iOS app.

Reading the AppMetadataSpecifications5.2 PDF document, I was intrigued by this paragraph:

> An unlimited number of intervals are allowed; however, for each interval, there is a period of several hours where the product will be unavailable for sale while the price is changed.

“Unavailable for sale for a period of several hours”?!

I really hope this is a bug in Transformer's documentation because otherwise Transformer would be a terrible tool.

- Is somebody using Transporter (or iTunesConnect) experiencing unavailability periods?
- Is it something specific to Transporter or does it also apply to the old iTunesConnect manual way of scheduling such price tier changes?

Comment: My two cents: the behaviour I've always seen when changing prices with iTunes Connect (iTunes Store Transporter should be the same) is that the price change takes some hours, but the app is live all the time with the previous price till the change is effective in Apple's servers. I don't have experience with iTunes Store Transporter so I can't post this as an answer.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the question that another line explicitly mentions the delay (which sounds fair enough): "The minimum interval duration is one day, and each change will take several hours to appear in the store while the cache is updated."

Comment: That is the exact way it works. Now I remember, I have heard apps disappearing for hours when there was a change in Apple's search algorithm. So I guess that they say the app may disappear so you couldn't complain if that happened to you. But it is not the normal behaviour. The normal one is that the price change takes effect in some hours and during the change you may see the old and the new prices. It probably depends on the change propagation through servers.